# Filter a gallery in Power Apps based on data from two SharePoint lists

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, power-platform

I used the Filter function to filter the "checkedOutVehicle" list based on conditions involving data from the "CheckedInVehicle" list. No errors, just a delegation warning, and no data retrieval from the SharePoint lists.

I have a Gallery control named "OutGallery," and I'd like to apply filters to the "checkedOutVehicle" list based on the conditions of the agreement and car number in comparison to the "CheckedInVehicle" list. If the agreement and car number are already present in the "CheckedInVehicle" list, I want to exclude them from the Gallery, I used the following code in the Items property of the Gallery:

```
Filter(
    Filter(
        CarRentalAgreements,
        'TextSearch-In'.Text in ['Agreement No'] || 'TextSearch-In'.Text in ['Car No']
    ),
    !IsBlank(
        LookUp(
            'Check-In Agreements',
            Agreement = 'Agreement No' && Car = 'Car No'
        )
    ) = false
)
```

After removing the below line code for the search box functionality, the data appears in the gallery but I need the search to apply also on gallery:

```
'TextSearch-In'.Text in ['Agreement No'] || 'TextSearch-In'.Text in ['Car No']
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are 'Agreement No' and 'Car No' columns available in both the lists?

Answer (score 0):

Try using formula like below for `items` property of your gallery control:

```
Filter(
    Filter(
        CarRentalAgreements,
        'TextSearch-In'.Text in 'Agreement No' || 'TextSearch-In'.Text in 'Car No'
    ),
    !IsBlank(LookUp('Check-In Agreements', Agreement = 'Agreement No' && Car = 'Car No')) = false
)
```

You do not need `[]` in column names. If you have space in between column names, just wrap those in single quotes like `'Agreement No'`.